# Can't refresh the calendar in "Day View Scheduler" angular calendar

Tags: angular

I am using the calendar to display appointments in "day view scheduler", getting records from server end and binding event to calendar but I am facing a issue to load data in view when page loads or when I insert new event and it is showing if i do next or previous but not first time when data load. I have tried to figure out it with the help of refresh.next() or by calling change detector when data loads and add to calendar events but no luck.

Here is the reference:-
https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/day-view-scheduler

Please suggest me any event or the way so that I can able to see my data in calendar view on page loads or whenever new data added.

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind the data using `[refresh]='component Variable name as refresh'` in your component view section (week or day, month, OR customViewComponent for day Scheduler).

In `component.html`:

```html
<mwl-calendar-week-view  [viewDate]="viewDate"[dayStartHour]="dayStartHour" [events]="events"  [refresh]="refresh"
            (dayHeaderClicked)="clickedDate($event.day.date)"
            (hourSegmentClicked)="clickedDate('week',$event.date)">
            </mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

In `component.ts`:

```js
refresh = new Subject<void>(); //  declare this property for data bind in html
```

After loading events-data inside a method, add this as the last line in the method:

```js
this.refresh.next();
```

Most important: If the event data is set to `allDay:true`, then it will not display an hour segment. Use `allDay: false` or remove it from the event property.
Then it will dynamically display events after loading.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the date is a Date, not a string (check the refference) and use the refresh observable(this.refresh.next()) to trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.refresh.next(); after you load the data.